# why laravel routing not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel

Below in my `web.php` content

```
Route::get('/tripScheduler', 'trip_scheduler@index')->name('listTripSche');
Route::post('/tripScheduler/create', 'trip_scheduler@store')->name('saveTripSche');
Route::get('/tripScheduler/create', 'trip_scheduler@create');
Route::get('/tripScheduler/{sche}', 'trip_scheduler@show');
```

Below is my controller file(`trip_scheduler.php`)

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Redirect;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class trip_scheduler extends Controller
{
     public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
   public function show(trip_scheduler $sche){
        print_r($sche);
    }
}
```

Now when I visite `mysite.com/tripScheduler/1`, it should show me the record from database where id is 1. However, it is giving the following output for `print_r($sche)`

```
App\Http\Controllers\trip_scheduler Object (
    [middleware:protected] => Array (
        [0] => Array ( 
            [middleware] => auth 
            [options] => Array ( )
        )
    )
)
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `public function show(trip_scheduler $sche)` 
You're typehinting your controller, but you should typehint model

Answer (score 0):

Your show function like:

```
use trip_scheduler;

    public function show(trip_scheduler $sche){
            print_r($sche);
        }
```

**NOTE**: `trip_scheduler` is your model name

**OR**

```
public function show($sche){
  $rsltTrip = trip_scheduler::find($sche);
                print_r($rsltTrip);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are type hinting your controller `trip_scheduler $sche` which is why `print_r` displaying `trip_scheduler` controller class. Try this way

```
class trip_scheduler extends Controller
{
     public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
   public function show($sche){
        $resp = YourModal::find($sche);
        return response($resp);
    }
}
```